# IPAD Files App accessing Synology NAS

Tags: ipad, network, nas

For quite some time I have been able to access PC generated files backed up to my Synology NAS from an IPAD using the  Files app. Now however I can only access the  top directly level
Once I select a directory there is a long pause, then I get the message: Content Unavailable
I have access from IPAD to NAS because I tried a utility called DS File (trial copy) which gives me  access to all the files on my NAS.
IPAD OS 17.2 with NAS of Synology DS 220j running DSM 7.2